# How can I call a C++ dll in perl without using com?

Tags: c++, perl

I am looking for examples to call a C++ dll in a perl code without using COM. Can I use win32::API? The library is written in visual studio 2010.

Comment: the most reliable and common way is to write an XS extension in C which calls the dll. However it is generally a good idea to use the same compiler for everything if your not using COM beacuse of binary compatibilty. There are instructions on compiling perl with VC++ at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlwin32.html

Comment: Let me rephrase the Q: I am looking for examples to call a C++ dll in a perl code without using COM. The library is written in visual studio 2010. I was searching through and found declaring the method using extern C __dllexport and writing a perl script using win32::API->new() can help me achieve the same. Is there any links or complete example for the same?

Comment: The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API) has examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Create a C-based module using [XS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html).
- Create a C function using [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline%3a%3aC).
- Use [Win32::API::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aAPI). (If the DLL doesn't use the stdcall calling convention, you'll need to wrap the DLL with one that does.)

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I followed this link and it worked for me.http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2006/12/04/compiling-c-dlls-and-using-them-from-perl/

Answer (score 0):

Calling a C++ method or constructor, using Win32::API, probably no.

Win32::API doesn't support the C++ calling convention (__thiscall) on 32 bit windows. On 64 bit Windows, it will work since there is only 1 calling convention on Win64. The biggest problem you will have with C++ is ABI compatibility and name mangling. Win32::API offers no help dealing with name mangling. You will have to find the mangled name of each C++ function (which is a method in C++), and give that to Win32::API. Win32::API can work with arbitrary C function pointers, so a vtable full of C functions (as in COM), works fine in Win32::API, for an old example of this see, http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=969555 . Also you will have to know what C++ objects and C++ Standard Library are on an assembly code level. Win32::API not supporting the 32bit C++ calling convention. This is the first road block. I (one of the authors of Win32::API) might one day implement __thiscall in Win32::API.

COM/OLE was invented to not have to deal with the ABI issues between different C++ compilers. Win32::API will work without problems on COM objects, assuming you know how COM works in pure C. To learn how COM works in pure C, I suggest reading this article series http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C . Win32::OLE and Win32::API can be hacked together sort of as shown in the perlmonks example.